# How to get number of discounts in request with 3 related tables?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 related tables in mysql 8 :

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`status` enum('D','P','A','I') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D' COMMENT ' D => Draft, P=>Pending Review, A=>Active, I=>Inactive',
`sale_price` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
...


CREATE TABLE `discount_product` (
`id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
`discount_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
...


CREATE TABLE `discounts` (
`id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`min_qty` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`max_qty` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`percent` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
`description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
...
```

and request, which works ok :

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts.min_qty, ': ', discounts.max_qty, ': ', discounts.percent)) AS discount_info
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN discount_product ON discount_product.product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN discounts on discounts.id = discount_product.discount_id
    WHERE products.status = 'A' AND products.discount_price_allowed = 1 AND products.in_stock = 1 AND products.stock_qty > 1
    GROUP BY products.id, products.title, products.sale_price
```

Now I need with discount_info fields to get number of related discounts, something like :

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price,
    ( COUNT(discounts.*) ) AS discounts_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts.min_qty, ': ', discounts.max_qty, ': ', discounts.percent)) AS discount_info
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN discount_product ON discount_product.product_id = products.id
    LEFT JOIN discounts on discounts.id = discount_product.discount_id
    WHERE products.status = 'A' AND products.discount_price_allowed = 1 AND products.in_stock = 1 AND products.stock_qty > 1
    GROUP BY products.id, products.title, products.sale_price
```

But I got error :

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) ) AS discounts_count, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts' at line 2
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to count `COUNT(discounts.*)`, which means all columns.  Instead, try counting `COUNT(discounts.id)` or maybe just `COUNT(*)` or even `COUNT(1)`:

```sql
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.title,
    products.sale_price,
    COUNT(discounts.id) AS discounts_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts.min_qty, ': ',
                        discounts.max_qty, ': ', discounts.percent)) AS discount_info
FROM products
LEFT JOIN discount_product ON discount_product.product_id = products.id
LEFT JOIN discounts on discounts.id = discount_product.discount_id
WHERE
    products.status = 'A' AND
    products.discount_price_allowed = 1 AND
    products.in_stock = 1 AND
    products.stock_qty > 1
GROUP BY products.id, products.title, products.sale_price;
```